# WCF windows service to use https

Tags: .net, wcf, https, windows-services, wcf-binding

I am tasked with making some changes with an existing WCF service (I don't have any pervious experience working with WCF). This service runs as a windows-service. Client applications connect to it over http, make calls to methods exposed in Datagram.Services. I just have to change it so that client application can only connect using https ( and not http). Is it possible to do it just by making changes in configuration file? If so, any suggestions what need to be changed in config file below for accomplishing it. Also will the clients have to install certificate to connect to this application?

```
<system.serviceModel>  
    <services>  
      <service name="Datagram.Services" behaviorConfiguration="Datagram_Behavior">  
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="Datagram.Service" contract="Datagram.IServices" />  
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="MEX" contract="IMetadataExchange" />  
        <host>  
          <baseAddresses>  
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:5000/Datagram" />  
          </baseAddresses>  
          <timeouts closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:05:00" />  
        </host>  
      </service>  
    </services>  
    <behaviors>  
      <serviceBehaviors>  
        <behavior name="Datagram_Behavior">  
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />  
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />  
        </behavior>  
      </serviceBehaviors>  
    </behaviors>  
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled transport level security?

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36705/7-simple-steps-to-enable-HTTPS-on-WCF-WsHttp-bindi